# How can I get a count of rows for each unique value (based on combination of two columns)?

Tags: excel, count, unique, multiple-columns

I have the following excel spreadsheet (in Excel 2010):

```
State Sport
TX Football
TX Football
TX Basketball
CA Basketball
CA Basketball
CA Football
```

I'd like to get a count for each unique State-Sport combination in the spreadsheet.  So the result would look like this:

```
TX Football 2
TX Basketball 1
CA Basketball 2
CA Football 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks @Jirka and Jerry for your responses.  While both answers are correct, I opted to go with Jirka's response as the accepted answer because it allows me to avoid using pivot tables.  I wonder if this can be accomplished using vlookup?

Comment: it might be possible with `vlookup`, but I'm pretty sure it would be very convoluted! I personally prefer the pivot tables in your case since you seem to want the similar states and sports grouped as one single entry. `COUNTIFS` is otherwise the simplest solution, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in function COUNTIFS could make this job

[image: COUNTIFS]

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use a pivot table:

[image]

This pivot table has `State` and `Sports` in Row labels and `Count of Sport` in Values.

The layout is "Tabular Form" and I opted for "Do not show Subtotals"

You can easily copy/paste the table as values (to remove the pivot table and enable you to edit the table) and fill down the states to fill in the blank cells below them later using something like:

1. Select the column with 'State' as from cell `A5`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Hit <kbd>Special...</kbd> and select <kbd>Blanks</kbd>.
3. Insert `=` and press the Up key, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.